# Terraform Snowflake Provider Issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, terraform-provider

I’m getting the below error after upgrading the snowflake provider to the latest one (Snowflake-Labs) with all the required arguments been provided and I've also executed the cmd which is refered in the docs (terraform state replace-provider chanzuckerberg/snowflake Snowflake-Labs/snowflake) but resulting in( No matching resources found..) can u pls help me to fix the issue?

[error screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx7Zl.png)

Comment: Please don't link to images - add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text